# logback autoscan is not working intermittently in k8s pod

Tags: java, kubernetes, logging

Intermittently facing issue related to logback where it is not generating logs as per the latest logger levels configured even though ConfigMap gets updated successfully.

I was just updating logger level for `io.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector` from debug to error and vice versa.

logback.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 second" debug="true">

    <property scope="context" name="APP_INSTANCE" value="${APP_INSTANCE}" />
    <property scope="context" name="NODE_NAME" value="${NODE_NAME}" />
    <property scope="context" name="HOSTNAME" value="${HOSTNAME}" />

    <property name="DEFAULT_PATTERN" value="%d{ISO8601} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder>
        <pattern>${DEFAULT_PATTERN}</pattern>
      </encoder>
    </appender>

  <appender name="SOCKET" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SocketAppender">
      <remoteHost>consolidated-logging</remoteHost>
      <port>5644</port>
      <reconnectionDelay>10000</reconnectionDelay>
  </appender>

  <appender name="GRPCv2" class="com.logging.appenders.GrpcStreamAppenderV2">
      <host>consolidated-logging</host>
      <port>5644</port>
      <instanceInfo>${APP_INSTANCE}</instanceInfo>
  </appender>

  <appender name="GRPC" class="com.logging.appenders.GrpcStreamAppender">
      <remoteHost>consolidated-logging</remoteHost>
      <port>5644</port>
      <instanceInfo>${APP_INSTANCE}</instanceInfo>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNC" class="com.logging.appenders.AsynchAppender">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      <appender-ref ref="GRPCv2" />
  </appender>

  <!-- Configure Loggers -->
  <!-- 3rd party Loggers-->
  <logger name="com.danga" level="warn" />
  <logger name="com.google" level="info"/>
  <logger name="com.springsource" level="error" />
  <logger name="httpclient.wire" level="warn" />
  <logger name="net.rubyeye.xmemcached" level="info"/>
  <logger name="org" level="warn"/>
  <logger name="org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor" level="warn" />
  <logger name="org.apache.commons.httpclient" level="warn" />
  <logger name="org.eclipse" level="warn" />
  <logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" />
  <logger name="org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotation.ServiceReferenceDependencyBeanFactoryPostProcessor" level="error" />
  <logger name="sun.rmi.tranrsport.tcp" level="warn" />
  <logger name="org.jdiameter.client.impl.transport.tcp.TCPTransportClient" level="off"/>

  <!-- QPS Loggers -->
  <logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="trace"/>
  <logger name="io.etcd.jetcd" level="error"/>
  <logger name="io.grpc" level="error"/>
  <logger name="io.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector" level="error"/>
  <logger name="policy.engine" level="debug"/>
  <logger name="transaction.log" level="info"/>

  <!-- Configure default Loggers -->
  <root level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
  </root>
```

versions: logback-classic, logback-core 1.2.3, slf4j-api 1.7.28

As per `ls -la` pod output, symbolic links too get modified properly on pod(but pod logs do not indicate autoScan getting triggered even after this point)

```
root@rest-ep-85597b67b7-7dwjz:/etc/logback# ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Aug 10 05:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 05:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 10 05:40 ..2021_08_10_05_40_05.423996728
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Aug 10 05:40 ..data -> ..2021_08_10_05_40_05.423996728
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Aug 10 05:06 logback.xml -> ..data/logback.xml
root@rest-ep-85597b67b7-7dwjz:/etc/logback#
```

Heap dump shows that `lastModifiedList` in `ConfigurationWatchList` does not get modified to represent the latest timestamp when log level was updated.
Can this be because of symbolic link or something else ?

Also found below details from [link](https://fossies.org/linux/logback/docs/manual/configuration.html) but not sure if this is what really happening

> In short, when a configuration file changes, it will be automatically
> reloaded but only after several logger invocations and after a delay
> determined by the scanning period.